# How to make a HTML build from raylib

Tags: html, c, raylib

I am a beginner programmer and I was wondering how I would make an HTML build from raylib. I tried looking at the GitHub https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/wiki/Working-for-Web-(HTML5) I couldn't understand it. would you be able to write a simple step-by-step tutorial for me. please

Answer (score 6):

For the very beginning you have to install emscripten SDK. As stated at the site "Emscripten is a complete compiler toolchain to WebAssembly, using LLVM, with a special focus on speed, size, and the Web platform."

Installation steps are prety easy:

- git clone https://github.com/emscripten-core/emsdk.git
- cd emsdk
- git pull
- ./emsdk install latest
- ./emsdk activate latest
- source ./emsdk_env.sh

After this steps you will have emscripten installed into the directory you've cloned it.

Then, you need to compile raylib itself to be usable in Web:

Go to the `raylib/src` directory and open Makefile, find where EMSDK_PATH variable is being defined and edit it accordingly to your setup. If you downloaded emscripten into `/home/user/emsdk` directory then put it in there:

`EMSDK_PATH ?= /home/user/emsdk`

Fix `PYTHON_PATH` definition as well.

then launch execute `make`:

`make -e PLATFORM=PLATFORM_WEB -B`
Notice `-e` option. That option allows to propagate and override environment variables to makefile.

`Generated libraylib.a is placed in raylib\src\libraylib.a directory.`

After that you can cd into `raylib/examples/`, fix Makefile as described above and launch `make -e PLATFORM=PLATFORM_WEB -B` again.

After that you would be able to start `python3 -m http.server` in that directory, navigate to `http://0.0.0.0:8000/` in your browser and see examples.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet but thank you for answeing the question

Comment: This post helped me complete the convertion. Thank you very much for your time. I am goint to make a video tutorial on that.

Comment: Here is a video of the above procedure in detail, it works: https://youtu.be/j6akryezlzc